# Issues mounting / using RAID5 partition

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have been trying to get a RAID5 partition going on a home file server with limited success.  Thus far, I've managed to build the array, and I can mount it manually.

However, it creates the array at /dev/md127, whereas I was expecting to see it at /dev/md0.

Also, it doesn't automount, I'm assuming because I have to add the individual disks to /etc/fstab?  It certainly doesn't like it when I try to mount /dev/md127.  I can mount it using the GUI on the server, but commandline mount via ssh fails, anyway.

It's a software-based RAID array using mdadm.

Comment: I'm not sure if this matters, but is this a hardware based RAID (i.e., to manage it, you'd have to go into BIOS) or software-based?  And yes, automount at boot time would require editing `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: it's in software.  Sorry - slightly important detail.  Edited the post to reflect the change.

Comment: I see!  Until now, I've only dealt with hardware-based RAIDs; I've never seen this kind of problem before.  I've added the "mdadm" tag...hopefully someone else can help you!  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  Reformatted the partition using mkfs.ext4 and it showed up and mounted manually.  Added to /etc/fstab and rebooted and automounting worked as it should.